# extracting strings from mysql field

Tags: mysql, substring, extract

total slow moment day, i need to extract different areas based on what language is selected from a field in a mysql database

ex:

```
<!--:en-->Overview<!--:--><!--:es-->Overview<!--:--><!--:fr-->Présentation<!--:--><!--:ar-->نظرة عامة<!--:-->
```

so if my language is french for example, i want the part between `<!--:fr-->` and `<!--:-->`

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings processing is not the strongest part of MySQL. But here is one idea:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_name, '<!--:fr-->', -1), '<!--:-->', 1) FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

The easier way would be using a substring. You can find the index for the language on the string first. After that, find the index of the end marker () and extract what's in the middle, which is the value you want.

A more elaborated way would be using regular expressions. The implementation depends on the language you are coding on.

Comment: unfortunately i need to do this on the sql side since this is from a wordpress site that has about 8 million hooks into the code base for the results, i figured change the sql then the php code doesnt matter anymore

Comment: MySQL has substring and regexp functions

Comment: @cularis Regexps in MySQL return TRUE or FALSE only.